# Where has my RAM gone?

Tags: windows-10, memory, virtual-memory

I have 8 GB of RAM installed, as you can see here:

[image: amount of ram avalible]

… and in Task Manager, it's showing that I'm using around 500 MB.

[image: see here]

50% of 8 is 4, so 25% of 8 must be 2. Then why is it telling me that 500 MB is 25% of my RAM?

And what is this?

[image]

What should I do? Does this have anything to do with the virtual memory paging file?

[image: this]

RamMap shows this:

[image: pic of rammap]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have selected the `User` tab in Task Manager which will only show you statistics for processes that are running *as* your user. You'll notice that the column header in your first screenshot says:

```
    27%
 Memory
-------
485.3MB
```

This does not mean that `485.3MB` is `27%` of your memory, but that your user account is using `485.3MB` of memory and the total memory usage of your computer is `27%`.

As you can see in this screenshot, I have changed the value (through Right-Click on the column header) to show Percent rather than Values, this shows that the total memory usage is `61%` and my user profile is using `51%`.

[image: User profile memory usage vs. total system memory usage]

There are several other accounts that are not "Users" *per se*:

```
SYSTEM
LOCAL SERVICE
NETWORK SERVICE
etc.
```

All of these run processes, services, and drivers that require memory to function.

Comment: i don't have another user, trust me. and you can see the blank space beneath it, which indicates that there is no other users

Comment: @HomamGamer sorry maybe I understand your question wrong or wasn’t clear enough. In the third screenshot the task manager shows that 2.2GB of 7.9GB are in use, which is about 28% of the installed RAM. This 2.2GB contains system processes, user processes and etc. In the first screenshot you see that your user uses about 500MB of RAM. In Detail: All processes owned by this user allocated 500MB RAM. The above shown 27% are related to current allocated RAM of all processes. As I mentioned in the beginning maybe I understand your question wrong, in this case sorry for the confusion.

Comment: when "my user" is using more than 500mb, like now it's 2gb, the memory usage is 50%, so i don't think that it has to do with system processes or anything, it just acts like i have only 4gb of ram, at least for this user, where is the other 4?

Comment: Actually, it has everything to do with system processes.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with this answer, just not hard enough to drive it home. I've fleshed it out a bit to show the reasoning behind the answer.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Windows processes have an owner: the user that initiated the process and whose rights/credentials are used by the process. The other users" mentioned in this answer are invisible system users that windows uses to run background system processes under. The 485MB you're looking at only include the processes that run under your name.

Comment: click the *Details* tab and you'll see a lot of users there

Comment: thanks for the the help guys, still, windows is using a lot of my ram behind my back, guess i have no choice oter than buying 8gb more.

Comment: Why do you think you need to buy more? You have almost 6 GB available!

Comment: you're using only 27% of the total memory. Why do you thing it's not enough?